# Momentum of the Dirac field in terms of creation/annhilation operators

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, operators, momentum, dirac-equation

In Peskin & Schroeder, the Momentum operator of the Dirac field is given as:
$$
{\bf P}=\int d^3x \psi^\dagger \left(-i\nabla\right) \psi=\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\sum_s {\bf p}(a_p^{s\dagger}a_p^s+b_p^{s\dagger}b_p^s).\tag{3.105}
$$
I am having trouble deriving the right-hand side of this equation from the left hand, since I tried plugging in $\psi,\bar{\psi}$ in the Schrödinger picture but got stuck :
$$
P^i=\int d^3x\psi^\dagger (-i\partial_i)\psi=
$$
$$\int d^3x\int \frac{d^3pd^3q}{(2\pi)^6}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_p}}\sum_s (b_p^s\bar{v}^s(p)e^{-ip\cdot x}+a_p^{s\dagger}\bar{u}^s(p)e^{ip\cdot x} )(-i\partial_i)(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_q}}\sum_r (a_q^s u^s(q)e^{-iq\cdot x}+b_q^{r\dagger}v^s(q)e^{iq\cdot x} ))
$$
$$=\int d^3x\int \frac{d^3pd^3q}{(2\pi)^6}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{E_pE_q}}\sum_s (b_p^s\bar{v}^s(p)e^{-ip\cdot x}+a_p^{s\dagger}\bar{u}^s(p)e^{ip\cdot x} )\sum_r q^i(-a_q^s u^s(q)e^{-iq\cdot x}+b_q^{r\dagger}v^s(q)e^{iq\cdot x} ))
$$
$$
=\int d^3x\int \frac{d^3pd^3q}{(2\pi)^6}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{E_pE_q}}q^i\sum_{s,r} (b_p^s\bar{v}^s(p)e^{-ip\cdot x}+a_p^{s\dagger}\bar{u}^s(p)e^{ip\cdot x} )(-a_q^s u^s(q)e^{-iq\cdot x}+b_q^{r\dagger}v^s(q)e^{iq\cdot x} ))
$$

Now I would want to use the definition of the delta function to turn q to p and get rid of the integration over x, and the anticommuting  (?) terms to vanish but can't quite think of a reason why they should. Am I going about this the wrong way?
Edit: thanks to Hyperon's hints I was able to get to:
$$
P^i=\int d^3x\psi^\dagger (-i\partial_i)\psi=
$$
$$\int d^3x\int \frac{d^3pd^3q}{(2\pi)^6}e^{ip\cdot x}e^{-iq\cdot x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_p}}\sum_s (b_{-p}^sv^{s\dagger}(-p)+a_p^{s\dagger}u^{s\dagger}(p) )(-i\partial_i)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_q}}\sum_r (a_q^r u^r(q)+b_{-q}^{r\dagger}v^r(-q)\right)
$$
$$=\int d^3x\int \frac{d^3pd^3q}{(2\pi)^6}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{E_pE_q}}e^{ip\cdot x}e^{-iq\cdot x}\sum_{s,r} (b_{-p}^sv^{s\dagger}(-p)+a_p^{s\dagger}u^{s\dagger}(p) ) q^i(-a_q^r u^r(q)+b_{-q}^{r\dagger}v^r(-q) ))
$$
$$
=\int \frac{d^3pd^3q}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{E_pE_q}}q^i\delta^{(3)}(p-q)\sum_{s,r} (b_{-p}^sv^{s\dagger}(-p)+a_p^{s\dagger}u^{s\dagger}(p) )(-a_q^r u^r(q)+b_{-q}^{r\dagger}v^r(-q) )
$$
$$
=\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{2E_p}p^i\sum_{s,r} (b_{-p}^sv^{s\dagger}(-p)+a_p^{s\dagger}u^{s\dagger}(p) )(-a_p^r u^r(p)+b_{-p}^{r\dagger}v^r(-p) )
$$

But I still fail to see how the terms of the type $b_{-p}^sv^{s\dagger}(-p)a_p^r u^r(p)$ vanish from the final result.

Comment: Hint: $\int d^3 x \, e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}} =(2 \pi)^3 \delta^{(3)}(\vec{k})$.

Comment: this I figured I would have to use, my problem is with causing terms such as $a_p^{s\dagger}b_q^r$ to vanish.

Comment: Second hint: You have $\psi^\dagger$ in your expression for the momentum operator (which is correct) but you seem to insert $\bar{\psi}$ in your further calculation.

Comment: Last hint: $v_s^\dagger(-\vec{p}) u_r(\vec{p})=?$ Eq. (3.65) on p. 48 of Peskin/Schroeder might be helpful.